# Does @Inheritance default to SINGLE_TABLE, or does it default to "fallthrough" OR SINGLE_TABLE?

Tags: java, annotations, jpa-2.0

Consider the following scenario:

(The following things have been omitted: Constructors, Getters and Setters, @Column annotations, @Basic annotations, @Table annotations, imports and package declarations. The rest is EXACTLY as I intend it to be (even empty annotations))

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String aValue;//There are getters and setters for this, but I omitted them
}

@Entity    
public class B extends A {
    private String bValue;
}

//Missing @Inheritance here - JPA2 says "default" @Inheritance if it is missing
//But what does that mean?
@Entity
public class C extends A {
    private String cValue;
}

@Entity
public class D extends C {
    private String dValue;
}

//Missing strategy, whose default, according to the annotation interface, is SINGLE_TABLE
@Inheritance
@Entity
public class E extends C {
    private String eValue;
}

@Entity
public class F extends E {
    private String fValue;
}

@Entity
public class G extends E {
    private String gValue;
}
```

Quick summary of the classes without the syntax:

```
A (@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
B, C (no annotation)
   D, E (@Inheritance)
      F, G
```

If you were to follow JPA's spec, should there be

- A: tables for A, B, C, D, E, F and G, all containing id + classValue
- B: tables for A, B, C, D and {EFG}, with A, B, C & D containing id + classValue, and {EFG} containing id + eValue + fValue + gValue + DTYPE
- C: tables for A, B and {CDEFG}, with A and B containing id + classValue, and {CDEFG} containing id + cValue + dValue + eValue + fValue + gValue + DTYPE

Or is it some other scenario I haven't thought of yet?
I would test it, but I'm not sure whether it would be the implementation of JPA or the specification itself filling in the blanks of "What happens when an @Inheritance annotation is not missing, but has an undefined strategy"?
Personally I'm pretty sure C won't happen, but I don't know whether it will map like A or B.

Hence the question title:
Does @Inheritance default to "SINGLE_TABLE" (no matter whether it's missing or undefined), or does it default to "fallthrough" (check how the entity hierarchy above deals with things) and if that's not possible, "SINGLE_TABLE"? And what if the annotation is there, but doesn't have a strategy defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct answer is "It depends on your Implementation". From the JSR spec (JSR317 §2.12 "Inheritance Mapping Strategies"):

> *Support for the combination of inheritance strategies within a single entity inheritance hierarchy is not required by this specification.*

In this case, the root of your hierarchy is A, with JOINED explicitly specified so then you'd have tables for each entity.

Now if your JPA implementation supported multiple inheritance types per hierarchy, judging from the Javadoc and Source of the annotation, I would personally expect there to be tables for A, B, C, D, {EFG}

As you point out, if the annotation is present, the strategy is `SINGLE_TABLE` unless explicitly specified. As the Javadoc and the Spec refer to the treatment of `@Inheritance` in terms of class hierarchies, I would think that if the current class does not have the annotation, I look to the parent and up the tree until I either find an annotation, or I reach the root of the class hierarchy (and default to `SINGLE_TABLE`)

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this answer because it's the most correct one - Mikko's answer has holes in it (E should have a dtype) - and because it answers the question based on the specification. I upvoted both answers though, as I really appreciate them.

Comment: Part of the E is persisted to table A and that's  where it can find dtype. Having it twice would be pretty confusing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For me it is not 100% clear, does following in JPA 2.0 specification

> ```
> Support for the combination of inheritance strategies within a single entity 
> inheritance hierarchy is not required by this specification.
> ```

mean that:

1. if implemented, should honor all other constraints presented (most
   likely) or
2. if implemented, can relax other constraints presented.

Luckily reference implementation has chosen first option. With EclipseLink @Inheritance without argument defaults to single table and not having @Inheritance annotation at all honours @Inheritance annotation found from the superclass (does not have to be immediate superclass). These entities will be mapped to five tables:

- A: id dtype avalue
- B: id bvalue
- C: id cvalue
- D: id dvalue)
- E: id evalue, fvalue, gvalue

(B-E id being FK to A id)

Persisting entities works as expected, each entity is saved to tables of superclasses as well without problems.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add inheritanse annotation with discriminator parameter to see all info about this stuff just visit [a link]http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetDiscriminatorValue.htm

Comment: What? 1: "You need to add Inheritance annotation" - or else? What happens if I don't? That (what happens if I don't) is the exact question I'm asking here. 2: "with discriminator parameter" - did you know they default to the name of the entity if you don't specify a @DiscriminatorValue?

Don't get me wrong, I appreciate that you're trying to answer my question, but this isn't helping. Sorry.